# Is it faster cracking the wireless WPS pin code if I already know it?

Tags: wireless-access-point, backtrack

Is it possible to fast crack if I already know the wps pin code?

I am using backtrack 5, trying to crack use reaver.

I was using this command:

```
sudo reaver -i mon0 -b <targetmac> -vv --pin <wpspinhere>
```

but the result:

> wps pin cracked
>
> wps pin XXXXXXX

there is no password wpapsk.

Comment: There’s a bug report on this. In the meantime, you could try [bully](https://github.com/bdpurcell/bully), it’s built exactly for what you want. Haven’t tried it, though.

Comment: He never said he wants to hack his neighbor’s WiFi...

Comment: @Xavierjazz, user already knows the PIN.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a Tp-Link WiFi USB adapter. Install the driver and software for the adapter. In the software, there is an option to connect using a WPS PIN. Enter the pin and enjoy the wifi. or
Install **JumpStart** in your window. Follow the instructions and enjoy the wifi by inserting the WPS pin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: actualy you are unable to understand